# Not able to launch firefox browser with specific language in geb spock with selenium 3.3.1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spock, geb

I am using geb spock framework which was working excellent with Selenium 2.52.0 and I was able to launch different browsers with different languages. For that I have written below GebConfig.groovy file.

When I upgraded selenium version to 3.3.1 and Firefox version as 56, I am not able to execute test cases on Firefox. Browser is getting launched however not able to load the url and getting below errors. I have tried several methods, however for time being please refer below GebConfig.groovy and error details:

GebCOnfig.groovy

```
/*
    This is the Geb configuration file.

    See: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html
*/


import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

import java.util.logging.Level
import java.util.logging.Logger
/*
1) For testing on different browsers, On Edit Configurations provide VM Options = -ea -Dgeb.env=<BROWSER_NAME>
2) For testing from command prompt by using maven command, run the command :
   mvn -Dgeb.env=<BROWSER_NAME> -Dtest=<TEST_CASE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION > test

Note: <BROWSER_NAME> = "firefox" or "chrome" or "ie" or "htmlunit"
      <TEST_CASE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION> example: eSuite_MP_CON_09_Zoek_in_kennisbank_PDC                        */

//FUNCTIONAL SETTINGS
def final DEFAULT_BROWSER = "firefox"                            //"chrome" or "firefox" or "ie" or "htmlunit"
def final BASE_URL = "https://india.westernunion.com/WUCOMWEB/signInAction.do?method=load"

def final DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "nl"                                       //"en" or "nl"
def final REPORT_DIR = 'target/reports'
def final DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_PATH = "C://Users/IEUser/Downloads/"
def final USERNAMEAPP = "Testbeheerder" //was "Beheerder"
def final PASSWORDAPP = "March@2017" //was "Jan@2017"



//TECHNICAL SETTINGS
def final WAITFOR_TIMEOUT = 50
def final WAITFOR_RETRY = 0.5
def final WAIT_AT_KEYWORD_AT = true
def final WAIT_TIME = 1000


def browser = System.getProperty("geb.env")
//Default browser
if (!correctBrowser(browser)) {
    browser = DEFAULT_BROWSER
}

def envLang = System.getProperty("geb.env.lang")
//Default language
if (!correctLanguage(envLang)) {
    envLang = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
}

System.setProperty("geb.env.lang", envLang)
System.setProperty("geb.build.baseUrl", BASE_URL);
System.setProperty("geb.build.beheer.baseUrl", BASE_URL_BEHEER);
System.setProperty("geb.build.loket.baseUrl", BASE_URL_LOKET);
System.setProperty("geb.wait.time", WAIT_TIME.toString());
System.setProperty("geb.download.path", DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
System.setProperty("usernameapp", USERNAMEAPP);
System.setProperty("passwordapp", PASSWORDAPP);
System.setProperty("penguinusername", PENGUINUSERNAME);
System.setProperty("penguinpassword", PENGUINPASSWORD);

System.setProperty("geb.env", browser)

System.setProperty("USERNAME", USERNAME);
System.setProperty("DATABASE", DATABASE);
System.setProperty("HOSTNAME", HOSTNAME);
System.setProperty("PGPASSWORD", PGPASSWORD);

if (Platform.LINUX.equals(Platform.getCurrent())) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver-2.15-linux64");
} else {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver-2.15_win32.exe");
}
//System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/IEDriverServer-2.45.0_Win32_.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe");

environments {

    driver = { getDriver(browser, envLang) }

}

/**
 * Returns the browser specific WebDriver
 * @param browser Browser name
 * @return WebDriver
 */
private WebDriver getDriver(def browser, def language) {

    if ("chrome".equalsIgnoreCase(browser)) {

        DesiredCapabilities chromeCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", language);
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        chromeCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions)
        def chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities)
        chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        chromeDriver

    } else if ("firefox".equalsIgnoreCase(browser)) {

    // Case 1: which was working earlier
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile()
        profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", language)
        def firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile)
        firefoxDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        firefoxDriver

        // Case 2 : 
        /*FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setLogLevel(Level.OFF)
        def firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options)
        firefoxDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        firefoxDriver*/

        // Case 3 : 
        /*DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        def firefoxDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
        firefoxDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        firefoxDriver*/


    } else if ("ie".equalsIgnoreCase(browser)) {

        /**
         * For InternetExplorer: In order to set the browser language to 'EN' or 'NL',
         *  Go to, Settings -> Internet Options -> General ->
         *  - Click on the button 'Languages'
         *  - In the Language text box,
         *    Add the desired language "Dutch (Netherlands) [nl-NL]" or "English (United States) [en-US]"
         *    and move it up by clicking 'Move up' button
         *
         */
        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer()
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false)
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, false)
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, true)
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true)
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true)
        ieCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        def ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities)
        ieDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        ieDriver

    } else if ("htmlunit".equalsIgnoreCase(browser)) {

        WebDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {
            protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
                client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
                client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
                client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
                return client;
            }
        };
        BrowserVersion.CHROME.setBrowserLanguage(language.toString())
        // Turn off htmlunit warnings
        Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        htmlUnitDriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        htmlUnitDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        htmlUnitDriver

    }

}

/**
 * Checks if the browser name provided is the correct one
 * @param browser Browser name
 * @return boolean
 */
private boolean correctBrowser(def browser) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (null == browser || (!"chrome".equalsIgnoreCase(browser) && !"firefox".equalsIgnoreCase(browser) && !"ie".equalsIgnoreCase(browser) && !"htmlunit".equalsIgnoreCase(browser))) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Check if the language provided is the correct one
 * @param lang Language
 * @return boolean
 */
private boolean correctLanguage(def lang) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (null == lang || (!"en".equalsIgnoreCase(lang) && !"nl".equalsIgnoreCase(lang))) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}



waiting {
    timeout = WAITFOR_TIMEOUT
    retryInterval = WAITFOR_RETRY
}

atCheckWaiting = WAIT_AT_KEYWORD_AT
reportsDir = REPORT_DIR
```

Error Description:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -ea -Dgeb.build.reportsDir=target/test-reports/geb -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=52849:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\DurgeshProjectWork\Workspace\IdeaProjects\wu_bdd_geb\target\test-classes;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\spockframework\spock-core\1.0-groovy-2.4\spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-spock\2.1\geb-spock-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-all\2.4.7\groovy-all-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-core\2.1\geb-core-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-ast\2.1\geb-ast-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-waiting\2.1\geb-waiting-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-implicit-assertions\2.1\geb-implicit-assertions-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-exceptions\2.1\geb-exceptions-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\jodd\jodd-lagarto\3.7.1\jodd-lagarto-3.7.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\jodd\jodd-core\3.7.1\jodd-core-3.7.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\jodd\jodd-log\3.7.1\jodd-log-3.7.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\gebish\geb-test-common\2.1\geb-test-common-2.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.3.1\selenium-java-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.3.1\selenium-chrome-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.3.1\selenium-remote-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.3.1\selenium-api-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\3.2.4\cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.1.0\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.1.0\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.3.1\selenium-edge-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.3.1\selenium-firefox-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.3.1\selenium-ie-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.3.1\selenium-opera-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.3.1\selenium-safari-driver-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\com\codeborne\phantomjsdriver\1.4.0\phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\htmlunit-driver\2.24\htmlunit-driver-2.24.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.9.1\selenium-support-3.9.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.7.9\byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.9.1\okhttp-3.9.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.13.0\okio-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.24\htmlunit-2.24.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.2\httpmime-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.23\htmlunit-core-js-2.23.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\neko-htmlunit\2.24\neko-htmlunit-2.24.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.21\cssparser-0.9.21.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\9.2.20.v20161216\websocket-client-9.2.20.v20161216.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.2.20.v20161216\jetty-util-9.2.20.v20161216.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.2.20.v20161216\jetty-io-9.2.20.v20161216.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\9.2.20.v20161216\websocket-common-9.2.20.v20161216.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.2.20.v20161216\websocket-api-9.2.20.v20161216.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.3.1\gson-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.4\httpclient-4.3.4.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar;C:\Users\acer\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1.1\json-simple-1.1.1.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 specs.sprintOne.TC_001_LoginSample_spec
1520759641134   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1520759641140   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:8942
1520759642011   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.jGPMmTbag3iw"
1520759642327   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1520759643229   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
[Child 10700] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 10700] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1520759645835   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52856
1520759646171   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 6442450945
1520759646375   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1520759646387   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:5497
1520759646950   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.WwKvyKDi21YC"
1520759647155   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1520759647895   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
1520759650640   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52883
1520759651100   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 6442450945

geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script15207596390172071282656$_run_closure1$_closure3@51768776'

    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:382)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:371)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:111)
    at geb.navigator.factory.BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.<init>(BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.groovy:35)
    at geb.Configuration.createNavigatorFactory(Configuration.groovy:417)
    at geb.Browser.createNavigatorFactory(Browser.groovy:133)
    at geb.Browser.getNavigatorFactory(Browser.groovy:121)
    at geb.Page.init(Page.groovy:144)
    at geb.Browser.createPage(Browser.groovy:859)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:550)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:539)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:56)
    at specs.sprintOne.TC_001_LoginSample_spec.Step 0: Properties laden(TC_001_LoginSample_spec.groovy:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@36676c1a}, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@36676c1a}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@36676c1a}, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@36676c1a}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KMHBAIB', ip: '192.168.220.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
    at script15207596390172071282656.getDriver(script15207596390172071282656.groovy:131)
    at script15207596390172071282656.run_closure1$_closure3(script15207596390172071282656.groovy:103)
    at script15207596390172071282656.run_closure1$_closure3(script15207596390172071282656.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
    ... 17 more

1520759651155   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1520759651162   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:7479
1520759651750   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.gGnTCVSPMRcn"
1520759651983   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1520759652660   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
[Child 12052] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 12052] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1520759655598   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52919
1520759655906   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 4294967297

geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script15207596390172071282656$_run_closure1$_closure3@51768776'

    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:382)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:371)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:111)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
    at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
    at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:931)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:59)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:46)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@1827a871}, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@1827a871}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@1827a871}, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@1827a871}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KMHBAIB', ip: '192.168.220.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
    at script15207596390172071282656.getDriver(script15207596390172071282656.groovy:131)
    at script15207596390172071282656.run_closure1$_closure3(script15207596390172071282656.groovy:103)
    at script15207596390172071282656.run_closure1$_closure3(script15207596390172071282656.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
    ... 14 more
```

Can you please guide me on this front, because my requirement is very specific to launch browser in multiple languages as well. The GebConfig file is working fine for chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Firefox GeckoDriver? Does this test work with ChromeDriver?

Comment: Hello, Yes, this test run with chrome and I am using Firefox GeckoDriver. For Gecko I have defined System property in my GebConfig.groovy

Comment: Which gecko version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Geckodriver version is : 0.19.1 win64, Firefox version 56

Comment: upgraded selenium version to 3.6.0. But still facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by performing below settings:
Selenium version : 3.6.0
Firefox Version: 56.0
Geckodriver version : 0.19.1

Then performed below changes in GebConfig.groovy

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setLogLevel(Level.OFF)
        options.addArguments("incognito")
        def firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options)
        firefoxDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        firefoxDriver
```

Firefox launched successfully.

Thanks for your help on this.